# MAIL LARAVEL Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, swiftmailer

i am working in laravel 5.6 and i use mail function that is:

```
Mail::send('mail.tes', ['data' =>$userregister ], function($m) use ($userregister){
                    $m->to($userregister['email'])->subject("Testing email auto konfirm")->getSwiftMessage()
                    ->getHeaders()
                    ->addTextHeader('x-mailgun-native-send', 'true');    
                });
```

then i got error

> Swift_TransportException
>   Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified. ]

and dont have idea where or what is the path specified?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Mail::send('mail.tes', ['data' => $userregister ], function($m) use ($userregister){
    $m->to($userregister['email'])->subject("Testing email auto konfirm");
    $m->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
        $message->getHeaders()
                ->addTextHeader('x-mailgun-native-send', 'true');
    });
 });
```